# Change the default screenshot destination folder of "Prnt Scrn" key?

Tags: print-screen

Hello everybody,
        My `Prnt scrn` key is not working after deleting the Pictures folder. I tried to add a folder without any success. I thought changing the destination folder may work so how i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this with Ubuntu 12.10, and 13.04, I pressed the <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> key, and this is what came up.

[image]

Just choose the location that you desire, and click Save

Comment: I am asking about the `Prnt Scrn` KEY that directly saves the desktop screenshot in HOME/Pictures

Comment: The key that's on the keyboard right?  That's what I did.